# Las respuestas no se ordenan de acuerdo a los votos

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

> Cambié el título, era: **La mejor respuesta (y aceptada) no se muestra primero**

Según el [Tour](/tour), las *«buenas respuestas obtienen votos a favor **y suben a los primeros puestos**»* pero encontré una pregunta en la que esto no pasa.

Se trata de [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php), que como podrán observar tiene casi 1,400 visitas. Pues **ya tiene** una [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/638) con **27 votos**.

Es de lejos la que más votos tiene, sin embargo se muestra en tercer lugar de cuatro, lo que representa un riesgo que afecta a sobre todo a los posibles visitantes que lleguen de los buscadores (el riesgo es el *rebote*, que al no encontrar a primera vista una buena respuesta dan clic en *Back*).

El tema es importante, la pregunta es específica y la primera respuesta que se ve, *en mi opinión* parece un comentario.

#### Pregunta 1. ¿Pueden confirmar esta situación en la pregunta en cuestión?

#### Pregunta 2. ¿Es una situación única o se está presentando en otras preguntas? <sub>No he buscado otros casos</sub>

> La marco como [bug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug), pero necesitaría confirmación.

### Edición

Una revisión rápida a la lista de las [preguntas más votadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) me permitió encontrar estas preguntas, cuyas respuestas no se ordenan por el número de votos.

- [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)
- [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)
- [Qué significan los caracteres de "?" y ":" en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2130/qu%C3%A9-significan-los-caracteres-de-y-en-javascript)
- [Hackeo de sitio web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28370/hackeo-de-sitio-web)
- [¿Qué significa "use strict"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2184/qu%C3%A9-significa-use-strict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pregunta 1. ¿Pueden confirmar esta situación en la pregunta en cuestión?

No. La pestaña Votos funciona correctamente.

Verifica que estas viendo la pestaña `votos`, y no la pestaña `activas` o `más antiguas`.

[image: Pestaña votos]

> Pregunta 2. ¿Es una situación única o se está presentando en otras preguntas? No he buscado otros casos

Aparentemente, se trata de una confusión.

Comment: Entendido, es solo una confusión.

Comment: Si te sirve de consolación, yo también tuve la misma confusión hace unos días.